Multiple Kafka topics based on message values in logstash
I have a logstash output configuration as below. This is working fine.
output {
  kafka {
    topic_id => "topic1"
    bootstrap_servers => "172.172.172.172:1722"
    codec => json
    acks => "0"
    partitioner => round_robin
    compression_type => gzip
    max_request_size => 10485760
  }
}

Each message has a JSON structure and it has fixed key-value pairs. The values keep changing based on operation, etc.. There is one key as "ENV" which indicated environment. I want to send a message to different kafka topic based on ENV value.
I tried to read a value of message and add if around it but it not working.
output {
  if [ENV] == "DEV" {
    kafka {
      topic_id => "topic_DEV"
      bootstrap_servers => "172.172.172.172:1722"
      codec => json
      acks => "0"
      partitioner => round_robin
      compression_type => gzip
      max_request_size => 10485760
    }
  }
  else if [ENV] == "PRD" {
    kafka {
      topic_id => "topic_Production"
      bootstrap_servers => "172.172.172.172:1722"
      codec => json
      acks => "0"
      partitioner => round_robin
      compression_type => gzip
      max_request_size => 10485760
    }
  }
}

However it is not working as expected. May of the messages are getting discarded. What am i doing wrong? I have the values for ENV as DEV and PRD only.
I went through elastic documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/lookup-enrichment.html

input {
      # define your input here 
      beats {
      port => 5044
    }
  }
# we can use the filter to extract the namespace
# Make sure to parse it properly here 
# example if the namespace is part of the message, you might use grok to extract it 
filter {
    grok {
          match => {"message => "%{DATA: namespace} %{GREEDYDATA:log}"}
    }
# If the namespace is already a field you might not need grok and just 
  proceed with conditionals 
}
output {
  if [namespace] == "DEV" {
    kafka {
      topic_id => "topic_DEV"
      bootstrap_servers => "172.172.172.172:1722"
      codec => json
      acks => "0"
      partitioner => round_robin
      compression_type => gzip
      max_request_size => 10485760
    }
  }
  else if [namespace] == "PRD" {
    kafka {
      topic_id => "topic_Production"
      bootstrap_servers => "172.172.172.172:1722"
      codec => json
      acks => "0"
      partitioner => round_robin
      compression_type => gzip
      max_request_size => 10485760
    }
  }
}


This code only answer could be improved with an explanation of how Vikrant's configuration was incorrect.
